# url id is duplicated when click on the link

Tags: javascript, express, routes, pug

I am creating a small app in express.  This is a question and answer app.  The problem I am having is within the query string.  The query string below is for the "question"

```
http://localhost:3000/cards/3/?side=question
```

[image]

Now when I click on the answer I get the following query string.

```
http://localhost:3000/cards/3/3?side=answer
```

which comes up with the following 404.
[image]

Below is the code for the card.pug file.  Which has the anchor tag at the bottom.

```
extends layout.pug

block content
section#content
h2= text
if hint
  p
    i Hint: #{hint}
a(href=`${id}?side=${sideToShow}`)= sideToShowDisplay
```

Below I have the code for the route file and this seems to look ok. So I am not sure whether it is something to do with the link in the pug file?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { data } = require('../data/flashcardData.json');
const { cards } = data;

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
const { side } = req.query;
const { id } = req.params;
const text = cards[id][side];
const { hint } = cards[id];

const templateData = { id, text };

if (side === 'question') {
templateData.hint = hint;
templateData.sideToShow = 'answer';
templateData.sideToShowDisplay = 'Answer';
} else if (side === 'answer') {
templateData.sideToShow = 'question';
templateData.sideToShowDisplay = 'Question';
}

res.render('card', templateData);
});
```

module.exports = router;
Any ideas as to where I could be going wrong.  I have been racking my brains about this and can't seem to figure out why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the card.pug file.  It should be.

```
a(href=`/cards/${id}?side=${sideToShow}`)= sideToShowDisplay
```

as opposed to being.

```
a(href=`${id}?side=${sideToShow}`)= sideToShowDisplay
```

Although, I am confused as to why it duplicated the id?

Comment: Because of how resolving a relative URL to an absolute one works …